# Symfony 2, ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I have big problem because i can't make AJAX request in Symfony.

I have some code in template

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".data" ).change(change_selected);
    });
     function change_selected(){
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{path('validate')}}",
            data: {'name' : 'kk'},
            cache: "false",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(response) {
                alert('asd');
            }
    });
     }
```

and i made controller with function

```
/**
     * @Route("/validate_form", name="validate")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function ajaxeAction()
    {   

        if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
             $response = new Response();
             $output = array('success' => true);
             $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
             $response->setContent(json_encode($output));
             return $response;
        }

    }
```

when i run firebug and change a text in the input field then firebug return error "500 Internal Server Error - ...test/web/app_dev.php/validate_form""

Someone know why ?

Comment: Its server side error, and what is $request? don't you need to define params.

Comment: 1. Check out your server log/Symfony WebDebugToolbar/actual server response to see error details. 2. You should escape output returned by Twig's `path()` function using `| e("js")` modifier. You could also try using [FosJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle) - very handy tool. 3. Symfony provides a built-in `JsonResponse` to handle JSON output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you didn't init function with Request $request?

```
public function ajaxeAction(Request $request){..}
```

Comment: Yes, it was long time ago but you have true, I forgot about "Request $request"